# How to use multiple SQL statement in Google Search Appliance Connector for Database(V 4.1.1)?

Tags: sql-server, database, connector, google-search-appliance

I have installed windows connector for a database(V 4.1.1) from http://googlegsa.github.io/adaptor/index.html.

I want to use 11 SQL statements to crawl by using this connector. When I deployed the connector, I filled one form which looks like this:
[image]

There is only one option to add an SQL query.

Do I have to installed 11 instances of this connector on my server in different directories to use every SQL statement one by one or Can I use multiple SQL statements to crawl in a single installation?

Answer (score 0):

There is only support for one SQL statement per connector instance.  You would need to modify the original connector if you wish to do this in one.  Alternatively, you can deploy 11 instances of the connector.

Comment: Can I run the SQL queries in a batch file? By deploying 11 instances of the connector, do you mean to copy the directory and edit the adaptor-config properties with the new SQL statement and run the run.bat file?

Comment: Is there a way to modify the original connector? If you have any links to do that, can you please forward me. It would be very helpful